# Get Value between to columns in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
make:"AC"
model:"ACE"
generation:"1 generation"
year_begin:1993
year_end:2000
serie:"Cabriolet"
```

I want to wite a mongodb query to get cars if the model year between year_begin and year_end I tried to write it but not work this is my query :

```
> {'year_begin':{'$gte':1994},'year_end':{'$lte':1994}}
```

Comment: Your query should work. What's the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#and) and query should look like below:

```
db.collection.find({$and:[{year_begin:{$lte: 1994 }}, {year_end:{$gte:1994}}]} )
```

Comment: I tried it but I got a single year for example '1994' I have to search with this year between two columns values and if it found between this range begin and end retrieve all the document.

Comment: My bad i made a mistake and didn't change the year, also your logic is correct, the only mistake you made was to use $gte for year_begin and $lte for for year_end, this way you won't get the result for that range.